# How to plot such figure in python usng NETCDF data

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to produce a figure (shown below) using netcdf data and overlay stippling a 95% using ttest. I want to plot this graph in `Python`. Any help will be appreciated.

Figure, original source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEE07.png):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEE07.png]
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

input = Dataset("v2p0chirps_25_1981_2016.nc.nc")

xlat = input.variables["lat"][:]
xlon = input.variables["lon"][:]
xtime = input.variables["time"][:]

precip = input.variables["pr"][:]

latmin =  np.min(xlat)
latmax =  np.max(xlat)
lonmin =  np.min(xlon)
lonmax =  np.max(xlon)

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat = latmin, urcrnrlat = latmax,llcrnrlon = lonmin, urcrnrlon = lonmax, resolution='i')


m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()

parallels = np.arange(latmin, latmax, 10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[True, False, True, False],fontsize=12)

meridians = np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, 10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[True,False,False,True],fontsize=12)

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(xlon, xlat)

x, y = m(lons, lats)


cmap_r = mp.cm.get_cmap('autumn_r')

cs = m.contourf(x,y,  np.mean(precip[0:6574,:,:], 0) - 
np.mean(precip[6574:13145,:,:], 0), cmap="rainbow", extend='both')



plt.savefig("contour_map.eps")
```

Comment: You need to provide some code that you have tried so far

Comment: Can you share some data as well?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Unfortunately this data is very huge (2.4G)

Comment: But this data can be used instead of that in the script

ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/interp_OLR/olr.day.mean.nc

Comment: I suggest using some other projection instead of Mercator with your data, for example: `m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat = latmin, urcrnrlat = latmax,llcrnrlon = lonmin, urcrnrlon = lonmax, resolution='c')` as the Mercator is not suitable for latitude range -90 to 90 as the y values will be basically from -Inf to Inf .

Comment: Thank you very much

My problem concerns mostly adding ttest stippling.  

I can easily adapt suited projection
regards